# How to display different time period in one dashboard kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to create a dashboard in Kibana which must contain one bar chart which shows the weekly trend of **X** log and one metric (single number) that shows only the occurrence of the **X** log during current day. when I add these visualization to a dashboard they sync themselves with the dashboard Time range. if I set time range to ***today*** bar chart only shows today chart and if I set the time range to ***this month*** metrics show total occurrence of whole month.

How can I show two different visualizations with different time ranges in same dashboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of version [7.4](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.4/dashboard.html), you can set a different time range for each visualization on your dashboard that override the top-level time range in the time picker.

If you click on the cog wheel at the top right of the visualization, you can the click on ["Customize time range"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/dashboard-create-new-dashboard.html#dashboard-customize-filter) and set a different time range for the metric visualization.

[image]

Comment: Which version are you running?

Comment: its version is 6.4.3

Comment: This has been introduced in [7.4](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.4/dashboard.html), so your only option is to upgrade.

Comment: I add a filter to my metric visualization and it solved all problems.

Comment: Yes, you can also do that, but if you want to modify the time span, you need to go edit the visualization, save it and come back... a bit cumbersome, but yes, it works. It might take less time to upgrade than do all that :-)